# Trace unmanaged function calls at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, trace

Is it possible to generate a tree of function calls at runtime? I'd like to get a feel of what the program is calling.

This is essentially the same as breaking at a particular location, stepping through each function, and recording down what the function names are. I have no performance constraints.

I am using Visual Studio, but do not have to.

// edit

To clarify, if I had function `A` calling function `B` and function `C`, and function `B` calls function `D`, I'd like the following example output:

```
(0.01s) -> Function A
(0.02s)   -> Function B
(0.02s)       -> Function D
(0.03s)    -> Function C
```

I do not want a static call graph. I want what happens on the stack for each function call at runtime.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous:  Do you want to generate a call graph?  (Except for calls through function pointers this can usually be done statically, that is, not at runtime).  Do you want to know which functions are called the most or which take the most time?  (If so, you'll need a profiler or you'll need to manually instrument your code).  Do you want to programmatically break your program while it is running and get a stack trace?  Do you want your program to be able to query at a given place in execution to see what the call stack is?

Comment: Doxygen can generate a caller and callee graph, but not during run-time.

Comment: I'd like "Do you want to programmatically break your program while it is running and get a stack trace," hence the "runtime" part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make it happen with all sorts of different approaches, but I think your best bet is to just use a profiler.

Figuring out "who calls what how often" is exactly what that tool is for.

Comment: I don't want a tool that shows how often something is called. I want a tool that shows exactly the order of executed functions at runtime that is called at runtime.